# Signature from my Signed OpenBadge won't validate

Tags: mozilla, digital-signature, assertion, phpseclib, openbadge

I need to be able to issue Mozilla OpenBadges. However, the Validator at http://validator.openbadges.org says that my assertion is invalid and to verify the signature, even though I followed the documentation to the letter. The Mozilla OpenBadges method that performs the signature verification check is at http://github.com/brianloveswords/node-jws#jwsverifysignature-secretorkey

I've posted this question [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openbadges-dev/rHddoySpsKc) and [here](https://github.com/mozilla/openbadges-validator/issues/23#issuecomment-26600324) with my code and resulting assertion.

While there is some documentation, a full-fledged example of a signed assertion seems to be lacking. For some documentation that they provide, please see the following two links: 
(1) http://github.com/mozilla/openbadges/wiki/Assertions#signed-badges and (2) http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-signature.html#RS256Example

If you need anything more from me, please let me know. I've tried to be as detailed yet concise as possible here.

Thank you in advance! 
-- Freddie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I didn't have my public key file in the .pem format. The public key must be 65 characters per line and the private key must be 64 characters per line with -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- and -----END PUBLIC KEY----- for both keys as the headers and footers, respectively. With the payload correctly formatted, I was able to have it validate at the OpenBadges Validator so signing it with PHPSecLib was completely fine! 
Anyway, thank you neubert for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The RS256Example link says this at the top: RSASSA-PKCS-v1_5 SHA-256

So do this with phpseclib:

```
$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
$rsa->setHash('sha256');
```

Comment: I had included the top two lines in my code. Anything else you can suggest would be much appreciated! I'm currently trying out OpenSSL as a check to see whether PHPSecLib was the problem (which it really shouldn't be).